# LVP underlayment material

Tags: flooring, subfloor

I am replacing carpet with LVP in my bedroom, the LVP is going to flow into the hallway (no transition), I need to raise my wood floor 1/2" in the bedroom to match the height of the hallway, can I use OSB or should I use Plywood?

Comment: I’d use OSB, if you can insure no moisture.

Comment: No moisture issues. I am planning on screwing the flooring down too. Thanks  Lee!